# Text alignment for navigation bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, navbar, text-alignment

I am following a tutorial and then changing what I can to experiment and create something of my own. I knew I would get to a point where I wanted something different that what was in the tutorial.In the tutorial the nav link are aligned to the right. I am wanting them more center but still to the right so it doesn't crowd the title/logo.
I have commented lines out, changed sizes of different aspects, researched, and simply experimented. I know the answer is going to be stupid simple yet I could use some guidance. How should I fix my code?

[css image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZg5A.png)

[html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfVtq.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and consider updating your post with a [mre] of your actual code, not images! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS file, you can change the *justify-content* of the header class to be:

```
.header{
  justify-content: space-around;
 }
```

this way the elements inside the header tag get more squished together but still have some space between them; experiment with different values of *justify-content* like ***center*** or ***space-evenly*** to see what works for you.

Another approach is to change the *margin-left* value of the navbar class; set to something less than 20px for it to move to the left a bit more.

Also good luck on your coding journey!

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed and I seem to be good now. Again, thank you for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: Your welcome! you can check the answer to let others know that it works.